# Services not registered with Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I used spring-cloud-starter-eureka 1.4.5 and spring-boot 2.0.4 versions.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Below mention the eureka configurations in the project.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: project-name
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  http://secodaryip:port/eureka/,http://primaryip:port/eureka/
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${vcap.services.${PREFIX:}configserver.credentials.uri:http://user:password@localhost:8000}
```

The issue is, there are eight instances need to register in Eureka. For primary IP there is eight instances are registered but in secondary IP there are only five instances are registered. For secondary IP, also should have eight instances are registered.

Difficult to find any solution. Any help or workaround can be really appreciated.

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: @ Wojciech Wirzbicki Question is there are three instances are not registered with secondary eureka IP. But that three instances already registered with primary eureka IP.

Comment: Ok, maybe you should edit your question and add more deails.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients will connect to the first host from your `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` config. Only if it's not available the second host will be used.

Could you also post your eureka-server config? Do you have peer-awareness between eureka nodes? If you want to replicate services state between eureka nodes you should have something like that in your eureka config:

node1:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  http://secodaryip:port/eureka/
```

node2:

```
   eureka:
      client:
        serviceUrl:
          defaultZone:  http://primaryip:port/eureka/
```